# GCE Instance - How does /etc/passwd get populated?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

A fresh cloud VM using Google Cloud Platform has lots of users already populated in /etc/passwd 
How is and who is it putting in their as I can't understand the rules for its population!

Looked at machines instantiated in multiple projects and been unable to determine a pattern

GCP's are part of an organisation if that has any effect.

Comment: Are you using a startup script that is adding users?  Are you using one of Googles supplied base images for the VM instance?

Comment: No startup script, and using image_family redhat-7

Comment: I created a VM and see users root, bin, daemom, adm, lp, sync, shutdown, halt, mail, operator, games, ftp, nobody, systemd-network, dbus, polkitd, ntp, postfix, sshd, chrony.    Can you update your question to indicate if THIS is the list of users you are querying about?

Comment: No sorry I mean actual users - with home directories listed.

Answer (score 0):

> GCE Instance - How does /etc/passwd get populated?

This is managed by the packages that Google has installed in supported images. You can also add these packages to your own Linux builds. The exact process is not documented well, but you can study the source code on how Google implements authentication for VM instances.

[Linux Guest Environment for Google Compute Engine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages)